# Understanding Gateaux derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, gateaux-derivative

**Background**

I'm studying Gateaux derivatives and I find some difficulties to underestand the general case where the order of the derivative is $n>1$. First, I'm considering the following definition for the first-order derivative at $h(x):\mathbb{R}^d\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and in direction $g(x):\mathbb{R}^d\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ of the generic functional $F[h]$,
\begin{equation*}
F'[h;g]\triangleq \left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\varepsilon}F[h+\varepsilon g]\right]_{\varepsilon=0}
\end{equation*}
we can simplfy this expression by removing the variable $\varepsilon$ (since in the end it will be fixed to the value $\varepsilon=0$). Since the internal derivative is a "conventional" derivative in $\varepsilon$, we have
\begin{equation*}
F'[h;g]=\left[\lim_{\tau\to 0} \frac{F[h+(\varepsilon+\tau)g]-F[h+\varepsilon g]}{\tau}\right]_{\varepsilon=0}
\end{equation*}
then setting $\varepsilon=0$ gives
\begin{equation*}
F'[h;g]=\lim_{\tau\to 0} \frac{F[h+\tau g]-F[h]}{\tau}
\end{equation*}

**Questions**

The $n$-th order derivative is defined as
\begin{equation*}
F^{(n)}[h;g]\triangleq \left[\frac{\text{d}^n}{\text{d}\varepsilon^n}F[h+\varepsilon g]\right]_{\varepsilon=0}
\end{equation*}

Currently I have two questions about this expression.

1. I'm wondering if we can do, like in the previous case, a simplification where we eliminate $\varepsilon$
2. I'm wondering if, as it happens with conventional derivatives, we can write a recursion of the type
   \begin{equation*}
   F^{(k+1)}[h;g]=F^{(k)}[h;g]
   \end{equation*}

If the answer of the previous questions is yes, how do you prove it? It will be enough the simple case with $n=2$.

Comment: I do understand the confusion or conflation but "functional calculus" has a well-defined meaning, at the very least in terms of the tag I removed: it applies to a mapping of the type $f \mapsto f(A)$ which assigns to certain functions $f$ an operator $f(A)$ which serves to "apply $f$ to the operator $A$" in a precise sense. This notion appears in spectral theory, especially for self-adjoint operators on Hilbert spaces. Anyway, sorry for the rambling, and have a nice day/night/whatever time it is for you!